# Is there a struts config tool for Netbeans 6.5?

Tags: netbeans, struts

I have found [Struts Console Tool](http://www.jamesholmes.com/struts/console/help.html) but its development stopped in 2004, so it works with Netbeans 3.2.

Is there a way to install it under Netbeans 6.5?

Are there any options to edit struts-config.xml above the XML level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans supports automatic `struts-config.xml` modifications. For instance if you right click on your project and choose `New/Struts Action` Netbeans will not only create a new class, but it can also modify your `struts-config.xml` and add a new `<action>` tag. Of course it's not a complex GUI, but you don't have to manually edit `struts-config.xml` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool to write a very simple XML file? Especially when the IDE should offer you tag completion, member list assistance, etc, in the XML editor?

Comment: Of course I can live without it, but sometimes it would be useful.
Another simple XML file, web.xml has nice graphical support in netbeans, so others also think it is not needless.

Comment: I bet you could write an editor in a day. Excuse to learn SWT or JavaFX eh? ;)